# Process.Start C# .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, process, .net-6.0

I have this code, that work perfect in WPF with Net Framework 4.7, i passing the code to WPF with .Net 6.0 and the same code give me the error:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Here are the vars:

```
sv.Path = @"D:\Folder";
sv.Exe = "app.exe"
```

And here the code to execute the process:

```
Process process = new Process();

process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = sv.Path;
process.StartInfo.FileName = sv.Exe;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

process.Start();
sv.Pid = process.Id;
```

Someone know for what works in 4.7 and not in 6.0?

Edit: if I remove `WorkingDirectory` and set `FileName = sv.Path + sv.Exe;` works perfect but I need set `WorkingDirectory` for the app configs

Comment: Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-6.0#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-useshellexecute). If things are different between .NET Framework and .NET Core, that is almost certainly the reason. This is an example of why you should ALWAYS read the documentation.

Comment: The error says the path is simply wrong. You're using a path relative to your application's current working directory instead of the full path to the executable. It's equivalent to typing `cd c:\somefolder` and then `c:\originalfolder\app.exe`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, that is almost certainly wrong. As per the documentation, the `WorkingDirectory` property works differently depending on the value of the `UseShellExecute` property that the default value of the `UseShellExecute` property is different between .NET Framework and .NET Core. That is almost certainly the reason that the file being looked for is not being found.

Comment: Right, i fix adding process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true thanks Jhon

Comment: @Krypton why not use the proper full path instead? There's no shell in web apps, services or anything running on Linux or MacOS. Why tie your code to Windows Explorer for no reason?

Comment: Some apps to run need workingdirectory to autogenerate configs/cache or somethings. Look a old video when i execute with full path the app closed

https://streamable.com/5z1xgj

Comment: @John I've been using .NET Core for so long that I forgot about this. This isn't just a change in defaults and can cause problems in .NET Framework too.. When you use `UseShellExecute` you aren't running anything yourself. You're using the shell/Windows Explorer, to go to that folder and start the file using whatever the configured `Open` command is. Depending on the application type and Windows version, there may not be a shell for .NET Framework to use

Comment: @Krypton that's not what I said. Yes, you need to set the working directory. You should *not* assume your relative path is relative to that directory though. Are you sure `UseShellExecute` will run in a web app? On Windows Server Core? There's no Windows Shell there. There's definitely no Windows shell on Linux

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I've forgotten about it in the past too but I made a specific effort to commit it to memory when I missed it once a while back. Once it's in, it's in for good. ;-)